# Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'sc'

Tags: unit-test, controller, class

```
global with sharing class Controller { 
  public String actId{get;set;}

    public treeInlineController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        List<Contact> = new List<contact>();



@isTest
    public class Controller_Test{
        static testMethod void unitTest() {

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to create an ApexPages.StandardController instance and then pass that to new treeInlineController as an argument. And passing as an argument does not need, or allow, the type to be specified. Simply pass sc.

Answer (score 3):

Update your test class -

```
Folder_Items__c fc = new Folder_Items__c();
// fc.field = value
insert fc;
treeInlineController objInline = new treeInlineController(new ApexPages.StandardController(fc));
```

Comment: thanks @Peeyush, its working and my test class covered 100%

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, when you are instantiating the object from class treeInlineController. The constructor is expecting the parameter of type `ApexPages.StandardController`

So pass the parameter in the constructor in your test class

```
Folder_Items__c folderitem = new Folder_Items__c();
//additional code here
treeInlineController objInline = new treeInlineController(new ApexPages.StandarcController(folderitem));
```

Comment: `treeInlineController` constructor accept `ApexPages.StandardController` not Folder_Items__c  object

Comment: @ratan thanks! that's what I mentioned in the post but missed out on the code